# MySql : how to skip joins in subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I wrote a program about finding products sold in both France and Germany. On the other hand, I'm not happy with my subqueries. I have a feeling that all the joins could be skipped and done much faster, yet I could not find an answer to this problem.

Here is the code:

```
select productname 
from products p 
join [Order Details] od on p.productid = od.ProductID 
join orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
join customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
where p.ProductID in (select p.productid 
                      from products p 
                      join [Order Details] od on p.productid = od.ProductID 
                      join orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
                      join customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
                      where c.Country LIKE 'France')
  and p.ProductID in (select p.productid 
                      from products p 
                       join [Order Details] od on p.productid = od.ProductID 
                       join orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
                       join customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
                       where c.Country  LIKE 'Germany')
group by productname
```

So what I'm asking for is to maybe simplify this as much as possible but in basic ways, or show the way to skip that joins etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWlzn.png

Comment: Can you provide a diagram of your database/table structure (ERM) and some examples?

Comment: Of course, I added a link with a picture of the database @it-person

Comment: @Przemyslaw: 

Did you try this:
SQL Query ::: `select ProductName from products p join order_details od on 
p.ProductID = od.ProductID  left join orders o on o.OrderID = od.OrderID  left join Customers c on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID  where c.Country in ('France', 'Germany') group by ProductName;`

Comment: Try to turn `IN ( SELECT ...)` into `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select productname 
from products p 
join [Order Details] od on p.productid=od.ProductID 
join orders o on od.OrderID=o.OrderID 
join customers c on o.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
where c.Country in ('France', 'Germany') 
group by productname 
having COUNT(DISTINCT c.Country) = 2;
```